What justifies the use of global coordinates when computing the $L^p(\mathbb{T}^n)$ norm?
Consider the $n$ dimensional torus $\mathbb{T}^n$. The $L^p$ spaces over $\mathbb{T}^n$ is defined as consisting of an equivalence class of functions satisfying:
$$\int_{\mathbb{T}^n}|f|^p < \infty. \tag{1}$$
For simplicity suppose $n = 1$ so that $\mathbb{T}^1$ can be identified as the unit interval with periodic boundary conditions. Thus in practice (1) is often computed as
$$\int_0^1 |f(x)|^p dx < \infty. \tag{2}$$
However, it is well known that as a smooth manifold $T^1 \cong S^1$ does not have a global coordinate chart. Thus I am confused on what justifies (2), where one set of coordinates are used to compute the norm over the whole space.

The torus minus a set of measure zero has a global coordinate chart.

You don't need a global coordinate chart, you just need to know that an integral over $S^1$ with respect to Haar measure can be computed by pulling the function back to $\mathbb{R}$ and integrating over any period, and similarly for the higher-dimensional case.
Said another way, there's a continuous map $[0, 1] \to S^1$ which is not a homeomorphism but is an "isomorphism on measure spaces modulo null sets" (we can just delete the endpoints of $[0, 1]$ and the point in $S^1$ they map to) so it doesn't matter which one you use to compute integrals.

Thank you! I assume this reasoning is valid in higher dimensions as well? For example, in $\mathbb{T}^n$ we would delete $n$ points (one in each dimension), and since this set has measure zero there is still an isomorphism modulo this set so we can compute the integral as if the domain was the $n$-cube?

@CBBAM: yes, there's no issue with this.

Thanks for all the help!

@CBBAM: in $n$ dimensions, you would delete the entire boundary of the square and its image in the torus, not just $n$ points.

In $n$ dimensions, you're not deleting $n$ points, but $n$ hypersurfaces (i.e., $\Bbb T^{n-1}$'s), right?

I understood the OP to mean: rewrite the integral over $T^n$ as an $n$-fold iterated integral over $n$ copies of $S^1$, then delete a point in each of these copies of $S^1$. In any case the point is you delete a set of measure zero.
